# Finding recurrence functions in a code snippets

Tags: recursion, recurrence

I am supposed to find the recurrence function of this snippet of code, but I am really confused if what I am doing is right. I will put --- lines to try to show my way of thinking.

Assume the tree is balanced.

```
// compute tree height (longest root-to-leaf path)
int height(TreeNode* root) {
if (root == NULL) return 0; **-------- C**
else {
         // Find height of left subtree, height of right subtree
         //Use results to determine height of tree

         return 1 + max(height(root->left), height(root->right)); **---- n/2**
      }
}
```

I believe the recurrence function of this code would be T(n) = c + n/2, however I feel like I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence relation will be:

**T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1**

At any level there is some operation on that level also 2 calls to the left and right subtrees.

We can derive the time complexity from here:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1
     = 2 [2(T(n/4) + 1] + 1
     = 4T(n/4) + 1 + 1= 4T(n/4) + 2
     = 4 [2T(n/8) + 1] + 2
     = 8T(n/8) + 3
     = 2kT(n/2k) + n
```

• Holds n = 1, 2, … Let n = 2k, so k=log2 n

```
     = T(1) + n log(n)
```

so the time complexity will be *nlog(n)*

Comment: Do you mind explaining where you got the times 2 and + n

Comment: Call height twice: O(N), each tree N/2 nodes make two recursive calls 2T(N/2)

Comment: Thank you but what about the + n, I’m not sure where that comes from

Comment: There was a mistake at each level you only check if it is root.So it should take 0(1) time. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Would it still be n(logn) then or would it be just n now

Comment: It will be nlog(n)